# more-routing changing routing drivers is not supported

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer to develop an application, and for routing i've used the more-routing component. It is working but it drops the following error:

```
Error: Changing routing drivers is not supported {stack: (...), message: "Changing routing drivers is not supported"}message: "Changing routing drivers is not supported"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: d
```

The full log looks like this (above I pasted the opened typeerror part):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'terminator_' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'terminator_' of undefined"}message: "Cannot read property 'terminator_' of undefined"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Errorpolymer.js:7309 TemplateIterator.getLastInstanceNodepolymer.js:7339 TemplateIterator.extractInstanceAtpolymer.js:7393 TemplateIterator.handleSplicespolymer.js:7301 TemplateIterator.valueChangedpolymer.js:7284 TemplateIterator.updateValuepolymer.js:7240 TemplateIterator.updateDependenciespolymer.js:6718 mixin.processBindingDirectives_polymer.js:7020 processBindingspolymer.js:6666 template.setModelFn_
```

in the 122. row of routing.html

How can i solve this? It is not so good to have such errors in the log... not too elegant

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one `<more-routing-config>` elements defined by your application?

You should have only one across all the imports loaded by it - more-routing can't support multiple drivers being active at the same time. This error is there to protect against that

Comment: there is only one. i checked this already, but there is an other error where the main element is added twice... and i don't know why. Of course the second time it says an error message and do nothing

Comment: That sounds like the issue then - I'd suggest either moving the <more-routing-config> out of your main element, or tracking down why it's being added twice.

Comment: Tell you what, I'll switch that error into a warning, and just continue w/ the first `<more-routing-config>` - any additional ones will be completely ignored